# How to change merge, nocommit to merge when pull the data in smartgit

Tags: smartgit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iawqF.png)Am using samrtgit 8.0.4.1 on windows os . When i am commit the code commited successfully, No problem. But pull the data from the server is pull the data with merge ,no commit. How to change merge? Please reply...

Comment: Do you mean "merge, not _rebase_"?..

Comment: yes got my point . And attached screenshot of myh system plz refer below link https://i.stack.imgur.com/iawqF.png .. Mikhail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the latest build (10125) from Help|Check for Latest Build. After successful update issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you click Pull, it shows you a Pull dialog. On that dialog, Click "More Options" and select how to do pull: with merge or rebase.

[image]

Comment: Hi I need Merge with commit.

Comment: For example 2 persons are use same git url dynamically. Person 1 add new data and person 2 pull the data from git. person 2 delete the data from the git. Person 1 pull the data from the git data removed changes did not made. There is a problem here. How to solve. Am using version 17.0.3.

Comment: You cannot simply "delete" data from git. You can either _revert_ a commit, or _rewrite_ the history with _reset_ (which is a dangerous practice). So, what exactly did person 2 do?

Comment: When we tried to update file in git, we didnt have any problems when we were using Smart git 7; we used to get "Pull (Merge)" in the output response. But, we are using Smart git 17 now and we are getting "Pull (Merge, no commit)" as the output response. We are not sure where exactly we are going wrong to get a different response. Please advise us on  the steps to achieve "Pull (Merge)" response instead of "Pull (Merge, no commit)" upon trying to update file in git.

Comment: Different message cannot be a problem by itself. Describe what problem do you have. Are you not receiving new commits on merge?